# Google cloud storage : Display private image in html page

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storage for media. My website is stored elsewhere. I just want to display an image on my website without make this image public. I tried to display this image like this:

- create API key for browser limited to my website (API key for http://*.example.com)
- display image on this website `<img src="https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/MY_BUKET/o/MY_MEDIA.jpg?key=MY_KEY" />`
- I can see in chrome console : ... "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" ...

I don't understand what I've missed, if I read the doc from google I'm lost: **I just want to display an image** with low security (but not public), not manage my media from my PHP app.

I can use google-api-php-client (my website is in PHP), but I don't know if I have something to do with this to make it work. I don't know where to start...

Thanks ! (I hope it's clear enough)

**EDIT:** I did not found any simple code example to render a private media in HTML using google-api-php-client; I'm lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "key=" parameter doesn't assign any sort of permissions. It's a less secure identifier that is used to tell Google which project should be billed for this otherwise-anonymous, incoming call. It won't get you access to objects that aren't publicly available.

The only way you could embed a non-public image into your web page would be to generate a signed URL when the HTML page is requested. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs for instructions on generating them.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot about clarification and the link, +1. What I don't understand is: I did not found any ressources like "these are the 3 lines of code needed to display a non-public image link in PHP with  google-api-php-client" :) ! Maybe this post can become the source for that info, if we work together ;), thanks.

Comment: @rap-2-h https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually

Answer (score 1):

If your app is hosted on app engine then you can use the [CloudStorageTools::serve()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/files/google.appengine.api.cloud_storage.CloudStorageTools) function to return the image as the result of a HTTP request and put in any access control you want.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my app is not stored on app engine